# Inequality on determinant of product of positive semi definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-semidefinite

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrices and $Z=X+Y$. Let $|X|$  be the determinant of $X$. Then can we say which one of $|I+Z|$ and $|(I+X)(I+Y)|$ is greater in magnitude?